# Swift NSMenuItem detect shift click

Tags: swift, macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I'm currently adding an NSMenuItem to my NSMenu and I'm able to successfully detect and handle the click event.  However, I want to add a second option and detect if the user has clicked the menuItem while holding SHIFT

```
let menuItem = myMenu?.submenu?.addItemWithTitle("Click me", action: "itemClicked:", keyEquivalent: "")
```

Is there any way to do this? I looked at keyEquivalent but I'm not seeing ANYTHING to how to get this to work.

Thanks

Comment: global watching for the shift/command keys work, but this code isn't executed when the user is navigating through the submenus so this doesn't work @leodabus

Comment: thanks for the response, i tried changing it to addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask and this still doesn't work..not sure why this was downvoted

Comment: any ideas @LeoDabus? Thx again

Comment: @leodabus i think the reason it isn't working is because my app doesn't have a window, i only have a NSStatusItem

Comment: can you reopen the question? none of these work and i'd like to post the actual solution @leodabus

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @LeoDabus for some help but I was able to solve this in the event handler for my NSMenuItem with the following code:

```
if let event = NSApp.currentEvent {
    if event.modifierFlags.contains(.ControlKeyMask) {
        // success!
    }
}
```

happy coding

Comment: should also work  `if NSApplication.sharedApplication().currentEvent?.modifierFlags.contains(.ControlKeyMask) == true {`

Comment: Note that in Swift 4, it becomes: if event.modifierFlags.contains(.control) { // success! }